# CRDB: DEFAULT NOW() in distributed database

Tags: sql, cockroachdb

I have 3 nodes of CockroachDb 2.1.4 and table with default value for timestamp column:

```
...
created_on            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT NOW(),
...
```

When I insert a line into the table and obtain this line I always get 
created_on = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z

However, when I try to reproduce it using docker and CRDB of 1 node, it works as expected.

I didn't find description of such behavior in documentation. Can somebody confirm that DEFAULT NOW() doesn't work when you have more than 1 node?

Comment: I cannot replicate this behaviour on multi-node clusters at either 2.1.0 or 19.2.0. Is there further detail around the anomaly you can provide? You might also try working though it on the [CockroachDB community Slack](https://app.slack.com/client/TP86H0JSH/CP4D9LD5F)